# Transferring photos from Mac to iPhone5

Tags: macbook, iphone, photos, transfer

I've got a MacBook Pro on 10.7.5 and I'd like to transfer photos from my computer to my iPhone5. What's The easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Use iTunes to transfer your photos to your iPhone. Make sure you have the latest version of iTunes if you are running iOS 6 on your iPhone 5. In the device’s Photo pane, you can sync photos and videos from a folder on your computer.

You can also use the iCloud Photo Stream to upload photos to iCloud, then they will show up in your photo stream on the iPhone. Just make sure you uncheck "Automatic Upload" or all new pictures on your Mac will be uploaded.

Comment: For what it is worth, be aware that if you have iOS 6 on your phone, you cannot delete photos off the phone that are transferred to it from your computer.

Comment: I have iTunes 10.7, and it says "Was not copied to the iPhone because it cannot be played on this iPhone". I am just trying to transfer a small jpeg.

Comment: You need to click on the Photos tab in iTunes and choose the sync location.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I don't want to sync a whole folder, just manually choose the images. I also tried with iPhoto and it wouldn't let me transfer TO the phone, only FROM it,

Comment: Set up sync to an empty folder to act as a drop box for any photos you would like to put on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

either use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or [BiTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync)
they will both sync everyting in their folder to the device setup with their applications, realy useful for phones, they also do it automaticly, works everytime :)

1. install Dropbox or BitTorrent Sync
2. copy the files you want to transfer to Dropbox folder or BitTorrent Sync folder on your mac
3. turn on your phone and
4. Install Dropbox or BitTorrent Sync on Phone
5. Make a folder in dropbox or btsync on mac and pick it in the phone application and then Let the folder sync (like a photo for phone folder)
6. Volla, you got your files on your phone :)